# View: Root Error: Invalid character in NaN / View: Root TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.negative')

Tags: metamask, mobile-wallet

I've created one react web application which is simply pass token between two users using metamask wallet. The problem I'm facing is, It's perfectly working fine in web page but getting **errors from mobile application**.
I simply open **meta mask** -> go to the **browse tab** and copy pasting my **deployed link** (netlify)[deployed link: [https://chipper-kelpie-925251.netlify.app/]](https://chipper-kelpie-925251.netlify.app/) -> then try to **scan the QR code** and click on **getRewards** button to call function of smart contract but it's giving me an error like, *`View: Root Error: Invalid character in NaN`* &  *`View: Root TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.negative').`* I didn't get any solution for this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.